# Select displaying weirdly in firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

So first of all, the fiddle :

```
.nav-ehri.nav-ehri-select {
-moz-appearance: button;
border: 0 none;
display: block;
height: 40px;
line-height: 20px !important;
margin: 0;
padding: 10px 0;
vertical-align: baseline;
white-space: normal !important;
width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dj2Ps/

The issue here is visible on Firefox but not on Chromium. For a weird reason, the select is not displayed like the button and I can't find the reason of that. I assume it is some firefox property I'm missing.

I am running bootstrap and have copied every css bits needed for this code snippet.

Comment: You need jQuery plugin to completely styling select element.

Comment: The issue is not how to change the select "display" but its position. This doesn't bug in chrome and I don't know which property I shall change to give it the right display :/